# registry product returns null

Tags: magento2.3

My phtml file is extended with this class:

```
class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions
{
    protected $_escaper;  
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData
      ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $pricingHelper, $catalogData);
      }
    private function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        if (is_null($this->product)) {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');

            if (!$this->product->getId()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Failed to initialize product'));
            }
        }

        return $this->product;
    }
```

When i call my function `$this->getCurrentProduct()` i get nothing, what i am doing wrong here. Its a product page

Comment: in what page are you using this?

Comment: @Marius its a single product page. if you need more information about XML files i can update the question

Answer (score 1):

This registry key will be filled only on the product detail page:

also, you may use

`$this->registry->registry('current_product')`

instead of

`$this->registry->registry('product')`

Comment: i have laready tried that without success sadly